# Scrapy extracting from Link

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract information in certain links, but I don't get to go to the links, I extract from the start_url and I am not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python"
    ]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'Books']), callback='parse')] 


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = DmozItem()

        # Extract links
        item['link'] = hxs.select("//li/a/text()").extract()  # Xpath selector for tag(s)

        print item['title']

        for cont, i in enumerate(item['link']):
            print "link: ", cont, i
```

I don't get the links from "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books", instead I get the links from "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python".

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `rules` to work, you need to use CrawlSpider not the general scrapy Spider.

Also, you need to rename your first parsing function to a name other than `parse`. Otherwise, you will be overwriting an important method of the CrawlSpider and it will not work. See the warning in the docs http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rules#crawlspider

Your code was scraping the links from "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python" because the `rule` command was being ignored by the general Spider.

This code should work:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from dmoz.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python"
    ]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'Books']), callback='parse_item')] 


    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = DmozItem()

        # Extract links
        item['link'] = hxs.select("//li/a/text()").extract()  # Xpath selector for tag(s)

        print item['link']

        for cont, i in enumerate(item['link']):
            print "link: ", cont, i
```